# Java Swing Interface Troubles

Tags: java, swing

This is the strangest bug I've ever encountered. 
Whenever I start my program, in about 1 of 2 times, the gui is successfully created and pop-ups. In the other 1 out of 2 times, I get no gui, I get no error and all the code is executed in the same order as whenever the gui is successfully created.

What is causing this bug? And how could I resolve this? I'm clueless..

The view class :

```
    package view;

import controller.GameController;
import lombok.Data;
import model.GameModel;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    @Data public class View extends JFrame {

        GameInterface gameInterface = new GameInterface();
        MainMenuScreen menuScreen = new MainMenuScreen();

        public View() {
            super("View");
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            displayMenuScreen();
            setVisible(true);
        }

        public void displayMenuScreen(){
            menuScreen.getSTARTTHEGAMEButton().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    GameModel.getInstance().newGame();
                    displayGameInterface();
                    GameController.startGame();
                }
            });
            setContentPane(menuScreen.getContentPane());
        }

        public void displayGameInterface(){
            setContentPane(gameInterface.getContentPane());
        }
    }
```

The Main Menu class:

```
package view;
import lombok.Data;
import javax.swing.*;

@Data public class MainMenuScreen extends JFrame{
    private JButton STARTTHEGAMEButton;
    private JPanel rootPanelMainMenu;
    private JTextPane crazyBananaRepublicTycoonTextPane;

    public MainMenuScreen() {
        super("MY GAME'S NAME");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setContentPane(rootPanelMainMenu);
        System.out.println("HEYHEY3");

    }
}
```

The class where the view is created:

```
import model.GameModel;
import model.GameModelObserver;
import view.View;

public class CrazyBananaRepublicTycoon {

        public static final void main(String args[]){
            View view = new View();
            view.setVisible(true);
            GameModelObserver gameModelObserver = new GameModelObserver(view.getGameInterface());
            GameModel.getInstance().addObserver(gameModelObserver);
            GameModel.getInstance().setGameModelObserver(gameModelObserver);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not properly using the Event Dispatch Thread...

You must only interact with most Swing/AWT objects via the EDT.

Change your main method:

```
public static final void main(String args[])  {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            View view = new View();
            view.setVisible(true);
            GameModelObserver gameModelObserver = new GameModelObserver(view.getGameInterface());
            GameModel.getInstance().addObserver(gameModelObserver);
            GameModel.getInstance().setGameModelObserver(gameModelObserver);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did it sometimes work and sometimes don't ?

Comment: It's called a race condition, and I'm too lazy to describe it here.  Basically, some things were happening out of the expected order, because two different threads were processing your code.   It could be a data-race, or an operation-race condition.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I didn't know multiple threads were invoked when creating this gui. Thanks alot again :)